# SSL rails nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install a SSL certificate that I recently acquired from GoDaddy. My web application is on Rails 4.2.6 and I am using an Ubuntu Server 14.04. I am also using Phusion Passenger 5.0.28 and Nginx. I don’t know if it makes any difference, but I launched the instance using AWS’ EC2.

I created a combined file using the two .crt files sent by GoDaddy.

When I edit my application.rb file:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

I receive the following error:

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

There are two files that I have tried editing, with not success so far:

1. nginx.conf. The server block currently look like this:

   ```
   server {
       listen  443 ssl;
       server_name  localhost;
       ssl_certificate      /var/www/primeraraiz5/primeraraiz_combined.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key           /var/www/primeraraiz5/primeraraiz.com.key;
       ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
       ssl_session_timeout  5m;
       ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
       ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
           location / {
               root   html;
               index  index.html index.htm;
           }
   }
   include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
   ```
2. rails.conf (in a sites-available directory; which is “symbolically linked” to the sites-enabled directory ). The server block looks like this:

   ```
   server {
       listen 443 ssl;

       passenger_enabled on;
       passenger_app_env production;
       root /var/www/primeraraiz5/public;
       server_name 52.39.200.205 primeraraiz.com;
   }
   server {
       server_name www.primeraraiz.com;
       return 301 $scheme://primeraraiz.com$request_uri;
   }
   ```

I don’t know if I am doing something wrong in these files or if I should change any settings at AWS or with the company that currently hosts my domain.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to do to your configuration.

The first is the server block containing the redirect. Since you haven't provided us with a server that's listening on port 80, I assume that you want to redirect all requests to `http://www.primeraraiz.com;` to HTTPS. If so, replace `$scheme` with `https` so that your block looks as follows:

```
server {
    server_name www.primeraraiz.com;
    return 301 https://primeraraiz.com$request_uri;
}
```

Next, the SSL offloading needs to happen in the server block from which you're serving. In your case, you're offloading SSL for server name `localhost`, and not for `primeraraiz.com` which is what I assume you're trying to do. So copy the SSL parameters of your first server block to the one that has server name `primeraraiz.com` to end up with:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name 52.39.200.205 primeraraiz.com;

    ssl_certificate /var/www/primeraraiz5/primeraraiz_combined.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/primeraraiz5/primeraraiz.com.key;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_app_env production;
    root /var/www/primeraraiz5/public;
}
```

Comment: I edited the rails.conf file following your suggestion; I also tried removing SSL parameters from the nginx.conf server block, but I still get the error message when I try to visits the website.